# Ruby code adding single \ to escape #, instead of adding \\

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, react-on-rails

ruby adding single `\` to escape `#` instead of double backslash

for example, the `#` in string `sd@#` is preceded with single `\` like this `sd@\#` automatically. I think it should add `\\` (double backslash) to escape `#`.

Is it a bug in ruby syntax? if not is there a way to escape it manually

Please help

Comment: To be honest, I don't understand your question at all. You don't even have to escape `#` in Ruby strings.

Comment: I am not escaping it manually, I am working on react-on-rails project, Whenever I submit the string ''sd@#'' from the react form, the string gets converted into "'sd@\#'" (ruby adds a single \ instead of \\\) on ruby side and it becomes an invalid string.

Comment: Are you sure Ruby does this? What gets passed in the params?

Comment: yes, ruby is adding it

Comment: Show the code where it happens.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single `\`to escape `#`. Also, there is no need for escaping `#` in strings. Both `mystring#` and `mystring\#` will give output `mystring#`

Comment: apologies for not being clear, But the problem here is the string is being sent to the service as json:
{"description"=>"sd@\#"} which is an invalid json

Comment: _"there is no need for escaping # in strings"_ – unless you want to suppress interpolation, e.g. `"#$$"` and `"\#$$"` give quite different results.

Comment: Better you should use JSON.generate() if you want to pass it as json